# Is it common to have a table with a field in a row referencing another row's id in the same table (fk)?

Tags: sql, rdbms, erd

I'm trying to build a url resource hierarchy (for a multiple REST services) that can be stored in a database. Example:

Say I have a main service like Store which has several API urls that you can create and submit to the database (kind of like how you configure aws API Gateway). So something like this would be one entry:

```
GET: https://<domain>//store/v1/api/product/category/mens-clothing/shirt
```

another one could be:

```
GET: https://<domain>//store/v1/api/product/category/womens-clothing/dress
```

yet another one could be:

```
GET: https://<domain>//store/v1/api/product/category/home-improvement/tools
```

yet another one:

```
POST: https://<domain>//store/v1/api/service/customer/{customer_id}/refund/item/{item_id}
```

So given the simple example of what I need to store and retrieve in a rdbms, I'm thinking I could do something like:

```
Table: services
id | name | version |

Table: resources
id | name | service_id (fk) | parent_id (fk) (reference to another row in this table) | index
```

Given the two tables, shouldn't I be able to construct the whole url doing something like:

*omitting the version and api resources*

```
<id=3 service_name>
<id=22 resource_name, index=0, parent_id=null (which means service is the parent), service_id=3>
<id=49 resource_name, index=0, parent_id=22, service_id=3>
<id=76 resource_name, index=5, parent_id=49, service_id=3>
```

as you can see, I'm attempting to construct for example /store/product/category/mens-clothing using a service name and resource indexing. But to do that, I would have to reference from one row to another in the same table. Is this common? Or maybe someone has done this in the past and can provide a better solution. Keep in mind that users are using this tool to create their own REST endpoints, hence the reason I need to build out this data model.

Comment: Self-referencing foreign key constraints are not nearly as common as foreign key constraints to other tables, but they are a common use-case.

Comment: @GordonLinoff does my use case seem plausible?

Comment: It is reasonable, especially if the database supports recursive CTEs.